# How to load images from Firebase cloud storage to flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage

I have stored my images on Firebase Cloud Storage and I want to put them on the icon. I want a function to pass the name of the image and grab that image URL for me but this approach doesn't work for me.

```
Future<String> downloadURLExample(product) async {
    String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('product_images/fruits/$product.jfif')
        .getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }
  
  String returnImg(String product){
    downloadURLExample(product).then((value) => {
      imgURL = value
    });
    return imgURL;
  }
```

I call my function as so:

```
returnImg(apple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `await` for the async function:

```
await downloadURLExample(product);
```

This is the full example:

```
Future<String> downloadURLExample(product) async {
    String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('product_images/fruits/$product.jfif')
        .getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }
  
  String returnImg(String product) {
    String imgURL = await downloadURLExample(product);
    return imgURL;
  }
```

And you could call the function as follows:

```
returnImg('apple');
```

You can read a bit more about `async` functions [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).